# Flutter TextField widget when otp autofill then need to auto submit next page, so what should i do

Tags: flutter

**Flutter TextField widget when otp autofill then need to auto submit next page, so what should i do**
->i need to do it without PinCodeTextField.

```
TextField(

                      autofocus: true,
                      autofillHints: const [AutofillHints.oneTimeCode],
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                      controller: textEditingController1,

                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          height: 0.0,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 23

                      ),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2.0),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14.0),
                          ),
                          filled: true,
                          hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey,fontFamily: 'Sans',fontSize: 18.0,height: 0.9),
                          hintText: "OTP",
                          fillColor: Colors.white),
                          maxLength: 6,
                      onSubmitted: (otp) {
                        // this.smsOTP = '123';
                        int length = otp.length;
                        print("onchangeee....");
                        print('$length');
                        if (length == 6){
                          verify(otp);
                          // print("resss $otpsendres");
                        }
                      },
                    ),
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/otp_autofill)

```
  late OTPTextEditController controller;
  late OTPInteractor _otpInteractor;
  TextEditingController otpCon = TextEditingController();

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _otpInteractor = OTPInteractor();
    _otpInteractor
        .getAppSignature()
    //ignore: avoid_print
        .then((value) => print('signature - $value'));

    controller = OTPTextEditController(
      codeLength: 5,
      //ignore: avoid_print
      onCodeReceive: (code) => print('Your Application receive code - $code'),
      otpInteractor: _otpInteractor,
    )..startListenUserConsent(
          (code) {
            RegExp regex = RegExp(r'\d+');
            RegExpMatch? match = regex.firstMatch(code ?? "");
            String otpString = match?.group(0) ?? "";
            otpCon.text = otpString;
        return otpString;
      },
      strategies: [
        SampleStrategy(),
      ],
    );
  }
```

In your textField just add the controller and set the other properties.

```
TextField(
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            controller: otpCon,
          )
```

This is the `SampleStrategy` class where you can set the duration of listening incoming sms. Hope that helps.

```
class SampleStrategy extends OTPStrategy {
  @override
  Future<String> listenForCode() {
    return Future.delayed(
      const Duration(minutes: 5),
          () => 'Your code is 54321',
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (length == 6){
    verify(otp);
}
```

You need to check the above case on "onChange" function of Textfield.

```
onChanged: (value) {
    if(value != null && value.length == 6){
    verify(otp);
    }
  },
```